# NS3 how to get the following attributes of node

Tags: ns-3, ad-hoc-network

I am new to `NS3`. I am trying to get these parameters from a node can someone please help me to get these parameters?

1 Computing Power

2 Numbers of Transactions

3 Energy Consumed for One Transaction

4 Node Latency

5 Bandwidth

6 Residual Energy

Answer (score -1):

All the available class methods are laid out in the [NS-3 Docs](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_node.html)